# Changing groupby keys on the fly

Tags: python

I need to split a sorted list of probabilities into groups. The first group contains probabilities from (0.5,1), the second (0.25,0.5) etc.

I've produced some code that splits a list containing powers of two less than 1 into two lists: one of list members greater than 0.5, the other containing (original) list members less than 0.5.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import doctest
N= 10 

twos = [2**(-(i+1)) for i in range(0,N)]

def split_by_prob(items,cutoff):
    """
    (list of double) -> list of (lists) of double
    Splits a set into subsets based on probability
    >>> split_by_prob(twos, 0.5)
    [[0.5], [ 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
    """
    groups = []
    keys = []
    for k,g in it.groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j, x): x<cutoff):
        groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups
```

Calling this code from the command line does exactly this:

```
>>> g = split_into_groups(twos,0.5)
>>> g
[[0.5], [0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
```

My question: how can I change the cutoff on each iteration? I.e. if I passed the function a list of cutoffs (e.g. `cutoffs = [0.5, 0.125, 0.0625]`, I'd get a list of lists each with the respective members of the original list grouped into the correct category. In this case the groups returned will be something like `[[0.5],[0.25,0125],[0.0625],[0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can just iterate over a list of cutoffs  using `x < i` for each i in cutoffs.

```
cutoffs = [0.5, 0.125, 0.0625]
def split_by_prob(items,cutoffs):
    """
    (list of double) -> list of (lists) of double
    Splits a set into subsets based on probability
   # >>> split_by_prob(twos, 0.5)
    [[0.5], [ 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
    """
    groups = []
    keys = []

    for i in cutoffs:
        for k,g in groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j, x): x < i):
            groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups

print split_by_prob(twos, cutoffs)


 [0.5], [0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625], [0.5, 0.25, 0.125], [0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625], [0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625], [0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]
```

Comment: Gosh, I spent well over an hour thinking about that! It doesn't quite do what I need - there are a few extra groups (for example, once I've grouped [0,5] on it's own, I don't want it appearing in any other groups), but I'm sure I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what I needed to do, and the full code is below. I'm not sure how efficient or pythonic it is however:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import doctest
N= 10 

twos = [2**(-(i+1)) for i in range(0,N)]
cutoffs = [0.5, 0.125, 0.03125]

def split_by_prob(items,cutoff,groups):
    """
    (list of double) -> list of (lists) of double
    Splits a set into subsets based on probability
    >>> split_by_prob(twos, 0.5)
    [[0.5], [ 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
    """
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j, x): x<cutoff):
        groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups

def split_into_groups(items, cutoffs):
    """
    (list of double) -> list of (lists) of double
    Splits a set into subsets based on probability
    >>> split_by_prob(twos, cutoffs)
    [[0.5], [0.25, 0.125], [0.0625, 0.03125], [0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
    """
    groups = items
    final = []
    for i in cutoffs:
        groups = split_by_prob(groups,i,[])
        final.append(groups[0])
        groups = groups.pop()
    final.append(groups)
    return final
```